# C++ DR 115: Address of template specialization even if deduction fails

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Defect Report 115 
(http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#115) 
says that if a template-id identifies a single function template 
specialization, it is considered to be an lvalue for that function 
template specialization, if template argument deduction (for the 
template arguments of the function template named by the template-name 
inside the template-id, I suppose) is not done, or it is done, but it 
fails.

I believe that the purpose of this defect report is to allow programs such as:

```
template <typename Fn> 
void f(Fn param); 

template <typename T> 
void g(T); 

int main() 
{ 
    f(g<int>); 
}
```

This is because in the call `f(g<int>)`, the type of `param` (`Fn`) is 
a non-deduced context since its respective argument used to be (before 
this defect report) a function template. This is covered by the "in 
contexts where template argument deduction is not done" part of the 
defect report.

What I have trouble understanding is why does the defect report also 
mention situations where template argument deduction is done, but 
fails. Why do these contexts need to be explicitly mentioned in the 
defect report? These situations are referred to explicitly both in [[temp.arg.explicit] p. 4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#4) and in [[over.over] p. 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#2).

I came up with an example which may be covered by the "contexts in 
which template argument deduction is done, but fails" part of the 
defect report, however I highly doubt that this was the reason why 
this part was added to the defect report. The example is shown below:

```
template <int i> 
struct B {}; 

template <short i = 0> 
void f(B<i>); 

int main() 
{ 
    void (*pf) (B<0> param); 
    pf = f<>(); 
}
```

In the above example template argument deduction fails because the 
non-type template parameter `i` of function template `f` is of type 
`short`, while the non-type template parameter `i` of class template 
`B` is of type `int`, and this situation is explicitly forbidden by 
the standard (at the time of writing this is specified in [[temp.deduct.type] p. 19](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#19)). However, the default template argument for the non-type 
template parameter `i` of function template `f` is exactly the 
required value (`0`, as in the type of `pf`), so this program should now be correct. However, as I 
said before, I do not think this is the example the authors of this 
defect report had in mind.

Why do contexts where deduction fails have to be mentioned explicitly 
in the standard?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If deduction fails, the default template argument is used.

Comment: Yes, but if it fails it means that there are no template arguments that, if substituted, would result in a specialization that has the type required in that specific context (except for the edge-case example shown in my question, which I do not think was what the author(s) of the final wording of this DR had in mind).

Comment: `pf = f<>()` must be replaced with `pf = f<>`, then the example is accepted by MSVC, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W3GbKn1n5

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, it seems like it should be easy to construct a case where deduction fails and the *template-id* should be interpreted as directly identifying a function template specialization:

```
template <class T = void>
void foo(T*) {}

struct S {
    operator void*() {}
};

int main() {
    foo<>(S{});  // Does this call foo<void>(void*)?
}
```

Deduction fails, so doesn't this mean that `foo<>` should be interpreted as `foo<void>` using the default template argument, and found to refer to a unique specialization, which is then called?

But alas, as far as I know, compilers have always treated this as ill-formed.

I noticed the sentence that the OP is asking about will be gone in C++23. It was removed by [P1787R6, Declarations and where to find them](https://wg21.link/P1787R6). In the list of issues addressed by the proposal, there is the following item under the "Templates" section:

> Richard’s simplification in [“Deduction failures and template-ids”](https://lists.isocpp.org/core/2020/02/8446.php) is applied as part of regularizing the interpretation of function names.

The link is to the reflector archives, which are accessible only to the committee, but with Richard Smith's permission, I'm going to summarize the discussion. Richard, like the OP, tried to determine whether there are any situations where the "where deduction is done and fails, ..." provision is intended to apply, and concluded that there aren't any. (Richard didn't say whether he meant that this sentence is always overridden by specific wording elsewhere, or that the compiler implementors just somehow knew that the intent of the standard did not match the wording.)

Richard also concluded that the set of contexts referred to by "or in contexts where deduction is not done" is empty. Deduction is always done.

This is presumably what led to P1787R6 proposing to delete this sentence from the standard.